What is meant by "When we construct conditional probabilities, the relative proportions of probabilities remain the same."?
In the course "Introduction to probability" John Tsitsiklis states the following:
"When we construct conditional probabilities, ...,  the relative proportions of probabilities remain the same.
Conditional probabilities are proportional to unconditional probabilities. "
The lecture can be found here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2f9EfEga4Oo&list=PLUl4u3cNGP60hI9ATjSFgLZpbNJ7myAg6&index=45&ab_channel=MITOpenCourseWare
and the statement at minute 8:20.
This seems to be wrong without additional assumptions.
If conditional probabilities would be proportional to unconditional probabilities then there would exist a number $a_B$ that depends on $B$ s.t.
$$a_B  P(A) = P(A|B) = \frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)}$$
For two events $A, B$ with $P(B) > 0$. This would lead to
$$a_B P(A) P(B) = P(A\cap B)$$
which holds if $A$ and $B$ are disjoint and $a_B = 0$ or if  $A$ and $B$ are independent and $a_B = 1$.
It does not hold in general. Consider for example $A$ with $0 < P(A) < 1$ and $B = A$. Then $a_A * P(A)^2 = P(A \cap A) = P(A)$ and so $a_A = 1 / P(A)$. But
$$a_A * P(A^c) * P(A) = P(A^c) \ne 0 = P(A \cap A^c)$$
Can someone please help me to better understand  J. Tsitsiklis statement or under which conditions it holds?
Maybe he refers to following equality:
$$\frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(C\cap B)} = \frac{P(A\cap B)P(B)}{P(C\cap B)P(B)} = \frac{P(A|B)}{P(C|B)} $$
given $P(C \cap B) > 0$, $P(B)>0$. That is, conditional probabilities are proportional to the probabilities of the intersection of the event of interest with the condition,  but I am not sure  if am am missing something and this is not explicitly what he said.

As @Sextus Empiricus mentioned in a comment,
when A and C both imply B, then the statement is true:
If $A \subset B$ and $C \subset B$, then
$$\frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(C\cap B)} = \frac{P(A)}{P(C)} = \frac{P(A|B)}{P(C|B)} $$
In general, for any event $A$,
$$P(A\cap C|C) = \frac{P(A\cap C)}{P(C)} = P(A|C)$$
Simply by definition of the conditional probability.  So the proportionality statement holds for the intersection of events with the condition.
Listening closely, this was the context in which Prof. Tsitsiklis made the statement "When we construct conditional probabilities, ..., the relative proportions of probabilities remain the same."

The probabilities of the sequences with 3 heads, e.g.
HHHTTTTTTT
HTTTHTTTHT
TTTHHTHTTT
... etc.

they have the value $$P(\text{some sequence with 3 heads}) = p^3(1-p)^7$$
and they have the same probability of occuring.
When we condition on the sequence being 3 heads, then the probabilities have the value  $$P(\text{some sequence with 3 heads} | \text{conditional on 3 heads occuring}) = \frac{p^3(1-p)^7}{\text{probability of 3 heads occuring}}= \frac{1}{10 \choose 3}$$
and they still have the same probability of occuring.

Thanks for the answer. I do understand the particular example. My questions refers to the statement in general, that "Conditional probabilities are proportional to unconditional probabilities. " since John Tsitsiklis seems to state that this statement is true in a more general setting.

@ChrisL the proportional probabilities of two specific events A,B, don't change when you condition on some other event C, as long as A and B always imply C. For example the relative probabilities of HHHTTTTTTT and HTHTHTTTTT don't change when you condition on the number of heads being 3.

thank you. You last comment  clarified the statement.
